# Similar logic but different classes (avoid duplication)

Tags: oop, code-duplication

I've got four similar class structures that are generated from XSDs, each one is a different version of an API.

The thing is, I have classes that operate on all these different class structures, but a good deal of the code is the same throughout all structures. I can't have interfaces for each class since all classes are generated from XSDs. Yet I want to remove duplication from my codebase...

What would be a good OO solution here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a little object composition. Define a class that holds the shared functionality and keep an instance as a member for each of your generated classes. Try to minimize the amount of mutable state you keep in the class so you can test it easier.

Comment: The problem with this would be that the classes are generated from third-party XSDs, so extracting stuff as external members would imply changing the third-party XSD, which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go for using a facade class. This class is your one point that needs to know about the other four classes. It deals with relaying calls to the correct class. This way you not only achieve the reduction of duplicate code, but you also abstract the API's from the rest of your codebase, making it easier to deal with changes in the API's.

HTH.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan... however, is there any pattern or suggestion on how to do it? I mean, that facade class would be just ugly in the sense that I would extract the behavior but the value setting/retrieval would have to be done "one by one". I'd have to make it maybe generic to tell which class I'm currently working with (ThirdPartyClassV1 etc)... any examples would be appreciated, since I still don't see how to implement this in an elegant fashion.